# Shouldn't the contributors be paid if LLM developers are being charged for Stack Overflow content?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, ai-generated-content

I've come across [this news](https://www.theregister.com/2024/03/01/stack_overflow_launches_api_to/) stating:

> Stack Overflow to charge LLM developers for access to its coding content

Now, the content on Stack Overflow or the sister sites aren't the work of Stack Exchange team or investors. It's the users who spend their time and energy to voluntarily share the information and keeping the website from becoming a mess by marking duplicate, voting, editing and keeping thing relevant; all of which is useful to a human user or a ML model. If Stack Overflow is making money off of their content, it's only sensible for the users to be paid.

I just want to clarify, that I understand traffic on Stack Overflow has reduced due to AI chatbots, and they need to make money to keep things up; but it annoys me that I share my knowledge for free so it should be free down the line as well. But, if someone puts a paywall somewhere, I should get a cut.

I am not looking for a definitive answer here, but I am curious to see if folks agree with this thought process, or am I possibly just overreacting?

Comment: Maybe we shouldn't be "paid" in real money, but at least have a guarantee that the earnings are invested back into the Public Platform in the form of implementing feature requests that we'all have been asking for so long. So far I haven't seen a huge commitment in this area.

Comment: I think SO sees the public platform as a cost center, not as a profit center.

Comment: By the same logic, why am I not paid a portion of advertiser's fees? Because those fees are used to keep the site running.

Comment: Heh, just wait till you have to pay to gain access to it.

Comment: Some people have alleged that the content we have contributed to the network is dual licenced, and that the second licence allows the company to redistribute that content without attribution. Please see https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/388760/334566 & https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/388571/334566

Comment: @rene see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/388586/997587 and my comment there.

Comment: Maybe in a few hundred years when society has had enough time to evolve beyond corporate greed. Right now, this is how it works. Even if we contribute content, we're still doing that in the role of a consumer. The content is the currency, that's what we pay with for this service.

Answer (score 35):

I think you are overreacting.

SE Inc has made money off of our content for years. People using our content have made money off of that themselves.  Heck, most of us get *some* value out of the content on SO.
LLMs entering the picture and SE Inc making money in a slightly different way does not change the equation much for me as a content author.

If anything, I'm a bit peeved at *LLM developers* making money off of tons of people's collective content and not giving back a share. But that too is just a symptom of the general situation of us making our content available for free.

Answer (score -1):

The profit goes to the business owner. The business owner dictates the terms of use. if you are unhappy with those terms, you can choose not to use the service.

Nowhere does the business owner specify that contributing users shall receive a cut from the revenue accrued from any facet of this business.

Looking at the filled part of the cup, you get to ask, answer, comment, vote, curate, chat and conduct other activities free of charge.

It is highly impractical to provide a pay-out for each contributor to the site anyway so to answer your question, you're not overreacting, you are seeking something that is not quite feasible.